# Multiple functions on single click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to execute multiple function based on condition on a single click event using jquery.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    var Acco_head = $('#Dashbordacco > li > a');
    var Acco_body = $('#Dashbordacco > li > div');

    Acco_head.first().addClass('active').next().show();
    Acco_head.on('click', function(event){
        if(myScroll != undefined || myScroll != null) {
            refreshScroller(myScroll);
        } 

        event.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){

            Acco_body.slideUp('normal');

            if ($(this).attr('class') = 'UE') {
                callPortfolioDataUrl(PortfolioDataUrl)
                }

            $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
            Acco_head.removeClass('active');        
            $(this).addClass('active');      
        }   
    });
});
```

here is the HTML:-

```
  <li class="UE"><a href="#">Upcoming Events</a>
  <div id="indexdata2">
</div></li>
```

but it throws an error like : "Left side of assignment is not a reference.".

Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `comparison operator`

```
if ($(this).attr('class') === 'UE') {
```

instead of `Assignment operator`.

```
if ($(this).attr('class') = 'UE') {
```

Try,

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    var Acco_head = $('#Dashbordacco > li > a');
    var Acco_body = $('#Dashbordacco > li > div');

    Acco_head.first().addClass('active').next().show();
    Acco_head.on('click', function(event){
        if(myScroll != undefined || myScroll != null) {
            refreshScroller(myScroll);
        } 

        event.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')){

            Acco_body.slideUp('normal');

            if ($(this).hasClass('UE')) {
                callPortfolioDataUrl(PortfolioDataUrl)
                }

            $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
            Acco_head.removeClass('active');        
            $(this).addClass('active');      
        }   
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Use `.hasClass('classname')` to check whether the source element is having the particular class or not

Comment: thanks Rajaprabhu, But will you please tell me if the class "UE" is one of the two classes of div then what should be the condition there to call that function as i am unable to serve my purpose even after the removal of error ?

Comment: @UjjawalKr Try my edit, You have to use .hasClass() to check that element is having that particular class.

Comment: tried this but it isn't working..i put an alert in that if condition..but after click it didn't work..

Comment: @UjjawalKr did you alert $(this).attr('class') what did that return.?

Comment: @UjjawalKr wait.! you have to make a hasClass check in your above code.!

Comment: it always returns false ...plz take a look at the html part...i have edited that in question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the assignment that causes the error:

```
if ($(this).attr('class') = 'UE') {
```

You should use a comparison operator instead:

```
if ($(this).attr('class') == 'UE') {
```

Comment: thanks guffa for your early response i get that right..but still unable to serve my purpose..seems that i put wrong condition there.Will you please tell me if the class "UE" is one of the two classes of div then what should be the condition there to call that function ?

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript the single equal(`=`) is used as the assignment operator while the two(`==`) or three(`===`) are used for comparison. The `==` will implicitly convert types before comparison so the `===` is better if you do not what type conversion to occur. To remedy your issue, change:

`if ($(this).attr('class') = 'UE') {`
to this:
`if ($(this).attr('class') === 'UE') {`